# How to apply a different version of a Gradle plugin?

Tags: gradle, jacoco, gradle-plugin

I am trying to use a newer version of the JaCoCo plugin and running `gradle dependencies` shows me that it's running version `0.7.1.201405082137` when I would like to be running `0.7.5.201505241946`.

Any idea how this can be done or if the plugin with the new version of JaCoCo is even available yet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out. I just had to add

```
jacoco {
     toolVersion = "0.7.5.201505241946"
}
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer if it solves the problem.

Comment: @Opal I must wait a couple of days before I can do so.

Comment: You can even use `toolVersion = "latest.release"` if you don't mind hitting the network to check during a build.